# Map the same function in several objects in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-management

I want to make a function to several objects, as below, The Treering is a function I created, but when apply it to the function ,it need object instead of character, how can I do this?

````
files = list.files("DTtreering",pattern = "^T", full.names = TRUE)
name = list.files("DTtreering",pattern = "^T")%>%str_replace(".xlsx","")
for(i in seq_along(files)){
assign(name[i],read_excel(files[i]))
}

for (i in seq_along(files)) {assign(name[i],Treering(name[i]))
}
Error in UseMethod("gather") : 
no applicable method for 'gather' applied to an object of class "character"```
````

Comment: Try using `sub` instead of `str_replace` (argument order will be different) and avoid use of `%>%` .  Then try re-running on a fresh instance of R without any packages loaded.  Also ensure you are in the directory intended by looking at output of `getwd()` .

Comment: Thanks，but also  report `Error in UseMethod("gather") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather' applied to an object of class "character"`
The below is the detail of function, I have to load several packages


`Treering<-function(data,time)
    {cdj<-gather(data,2:ncol(data),key="Id",value="Width")%>%filter(Year>1999)%>%mutate(Width=ifelse(Width==0,NA,Width))%>%na.omit()}

;name<-sub(".xlsx","",list.files("DTtreering",pattern = "^T"))
`

Comment: You are referring to code that was not shown.  If you use the code shown then it could not refer to functions in packages that are not loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.